# How do I add a new route to the PATH variable?

Tags: path

Although this question is being answered many times, I could not find any help from previous posts, so here it is again.

I have tried to add a new route to PATH variable with no success.

I have added the following command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/bin
```

to this files one at a time: ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc

After starting a new Terminal session I type

```
env
```

but the PATH variable never show the changes.

EDIT:

Seems that none of this files are being read when opening terminal, other routes where in this files and they are not being added either. On starting terminal I get this message "-bash: : command not found". If I execute

```
source ~/.profile
```

I get the route added to the PATH but it does not keep for the next Terminal session. How can I test what is happening on Terminal startup?

This are the contents of the files:

~/.profile

```
export PATH=/applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
export MANPATH=/opt/local/share/man:$MANPATH
export PATH=/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/bin:$PATH
```

~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/zend/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/zend/lib
```

~/.bash_profile is empty

None of the routes in any of them are displayed after typing

```
env
```

in Terminal.

Comment: Put some echo lines in the files to see what gets executed

Comment: You're doing it right. That should work.

Comment: @Mark, what do you mean with adding echo lines?

Comment: echo - $PATH will print out the path , put different echo "comment" in the files to show which ones are being used

Comment: @Mark, I have added `echo ".profile is used"` and similar lines to .bashrc and .bash_profile and none of this lines are displayed after starting Terminal, but opening terminal I always get the message "-bash: : command not found".

Comment: In Terminal Preferences what are values of "Shells open with" and also Settings->Shell->Run command

Comment: @Mark, "Shell open with: default login shell(/usr/bin/login)", "Run command: unchecked and empty".

Answer (score 1):

well first off you only really need it in  ~/.bash_profile if you have one.

Second opening a new terminal session without quitting terminal app will not source the  ~/.bash_profile file.

You can just type "source  ~/.bash_profile" in the terminal and it should pick up your new settings.

Or quit terminal.app and restart it.

Comment: I always quit and restart Terminal to verify the changes.

Comment: +1, the changes always need to go into bash_profile on OS X, .profile never works from the home directory only from /etc/, so bash_profile is the recommended place to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the export to:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/zend/share/ZendFramework/bin:$PATH
```

in your ~/.profile

Comment: Marconcini, there is no difference is setting the new route after or before the previous PATH.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in how you are testing the changes.

Run the following command in Terminal to test your changes.

`source ~/.profile`

Once it looks correct, start a new window and re-verify the settings.

Every time you run the source command it will add the same path to your $PATH variable.

Comment: the `source`command works but only while the session is not closed. See my edits to the post.